# Azure web app on docker container produces error but when run locally docker produces no error

Tags: docker, azure-webapps

I have a docker container that runs a streamlit app that creates a ppt presentation based on what we have in our data system.

when I create a docker image and run it on a local host, it produces the expected output.

when I set it up in an azure web app, the streamlit app throws an error. Specifically, the traceback error from the logs shows a specific line.

why might the containerized app work successfully when run locally, but not when run in azure web apps? I was under the impression that if one can get it working locally, it should run perfectly when hosted.

Have I missed something/ misunderstood? TIA

Comment: There are many reasons: different linux kernel, different syscall implementation, different environment/mounts, different runtime capacity, different permissions, etc. To help get an answer to your question, please add details preferably including a minimal repro of the issue.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, unfortunately I cannot create a MRE as there is client data involved. But isn't a docker container supposed to be fool proof, as the exact same commands create the same container and it does not matter when it is hosted, locally or in Azure?

Comment: I tried to answer that question in my first comment. E.g. containers depend on a Linux kernel (which may differ) that is accessed through syscalls (which may be implemented differently e.g. Google's [gVisor](https://gvisor.dev/)) which may have different security profiles. Also your container likely depends on its environment (variables, volume mounts etc.) and these may differ and, on the cloud, there's permissions (IAM) to consider.